# Redirect User to a certain activity based on Volley's response code (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-volley

I am trying to start an Intent based on the response code from the Server.
All the requests are carried out using Volley. Below is the Custom Request I'm using:

```
public class JSONObjectRequestUTF8 extends JsonObjectRequest {

public JSONObjectRequestUTF8(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
                       Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, jsonRequest, listener,
            errorListener);
    setShouldCache(false);
}

@Override
protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse (NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String utf8String = new String(response.data, "UTF-8");
        return Response.success(new JSONObject(utf8String), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // log error
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // log error
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}
```

In ParseNetworkResponse the error code comes correctly. However I'm not able to work out how to start an Intent from here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

And have a nice day.

EDIT: Code for calling the above class

```
public class AuditAPI implements Response.Listener<JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener {
private Context mContext;
private SharedPreferences deviceInfo;

public void makeAudit(final Context mContent,String ipAddress, int status){
    this.mContext = mContent;
        final HashMap<String, String> login_model = SessionManager.getInstance().getUserDetails(mContent);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JSONObjectRequestUTF8(Request.Method.POST, Constants.MAKE_AUDIT , null, this, this){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put(Constants.SUBJECTID,
                    login_model.get(Constants.SUBJECTID));
            headers.put(Constants.ACCESSTOKEN,
                    login_model.get(Constants.ACCESSTOKEN));
            headers.put("user-agent","Android");
            headers.put("DEVICEID",Constants.DEVICE_ID);
            headers.put("VAPPID", Constants.VAPP_ID);
            headers.put("LOGIN_USER_NAME", (MyBaseActivity.getmUserId()));
            headers.put("STATUS", String.valueOf(status));
            headers.put("IPADDRESS",ipAddress);
            headers.put("CONTENT_TYPE",Constants.JSON_FROMAT);
            return headers;
        }

    };
    jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(1,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    MyApplicationController.getNewInstance(mContext).
            addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, "AUDIT");
    }

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
    Log.i("Failure", "onErrorResponse: ");
}

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    Log.i("Success","onResponse Audit");
}}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code where you call the above class.

Comment: @HasanBouTaam I have added the code used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a fix which was a tad tedious but simple.
Basically I had to override the deliverError method. In that method the errorCode was present, as a result based on that code I was able to perform the redirection.
Also needed to pass the context in the constructor. Needed to make that change in all request calls.

The reason this worked as per my understanding is that deliverError is called when the worker thread needs is trying to merge back to the main UI Thread. This bifurcation is caused in parseNetworkResponse since it's a heavy process which is why a worker thread is assigned to it.

**Updated Class:**

```
public class JSONObjectRequestUTF8 extends JsonObjectRequest {
//This is a new parameter
private Context context;
public JSONObjectRequestUTF8(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
                       Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener,Context context) {
    super(method, url, jsonRequest, listener,
            errorListener);
    this.context = context;
    setShouldCache(false);
}

@Override
protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse (NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String utf8String = new String(response.data, "UTF-8");
        return Response.success(new JSONObject(utf8String), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // log error
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // log error
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}

@Override
public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
    if(error.networkResponse.statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_PRECON_FAILED || error.networkResponse.statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED){
        Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(EReceiptsConstants.ERROR_MESSAGE, EReceiptsConstants.SESSION_MESSAGE);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        context.startActivity(i);
        return;
    }
}
```